# Drawing a map from walk times only

Tags: java, python, algorithm, optimization, graph-algorithm

Given a set of walk times between nodes, is it possible to produce a map which is the best guess of the terrain?

The terrain is assumed to be 2D, and nodes are either walkable or not walkable. The speed of walking is constant between all nodes. Only about 1 in 20 nodes (in the grid model) will have arrival sensors.

**Motivation:**

I have a set of data which tells me when people arrive at certain points in a building, but I do not have any positioning system. I would like an illustration of what the floor plan looks like.

**Further complications:**

1. Can this be extended to 3D maps (e.g. different floors).
2. Can this be extended to consider edges that have different walk speeds?

**Example Resulting Floorplan:**

[image: sample floor plan]

Edit: Java/Python not important, they happen to be the languages I am currently using.

Comment: Are the paths between nodes straight lines? If not, consider the degenerate case where I leave Node A, walk in a circle in the hallway for thirty minutes, and arrive at Node B, five feet away from my beginning position. The only information you can derive from this event is that Node A and B are less than thirty minutes apart.

Comment: Is the java/python bit important here, or are you more interested in the algorithm?

Comment: Any additional information? For instance, a country or city might improve an estimate of average walking speed or provide some insight into building design. Is there any way to determine if someone stopped while moving between nodes, say at their office?

Comment: Is there an example layout of the nodes / the sort of ideal floorplan you'd wish to extract from this?

Comment: Do you have a data sample associated with a known floorplan?

Comment: @Richard: I can certainly get a sample floorplan into the system, but it would take significant work. I wouldn't be able to do this in general though.

Comment: @Kevin: the graphs are modelled as a square grid. Every square is a node, and is connected to 8 nodes (which may or may not be walkable). I believe this discrete model is the only way that computers can handle this kind of thing (- not sure if that's actually true...)

Comment: So, you're not really asking for walking time, but for the actual distance between the nodes in 3D.

Comment: @Tinctorius: The measurement recorded is definitely time. What I need from that is then the map which shows distances (and areas that can and cannot be walked across).

Comment: @cammill, I don't think there's a need to be able to do it in general, but you'd certainly want a test data set against which to verify any algorithm.

Comment: Any indication of which nodes in the floorplan you post have arrival sensors?

Comment: I agree, and that I would certainly do. It occurs to me that the walk times somehow inherently contain this information, so I wondered if this is possible, or has been attempted by anyone else.

Only about one in 20 nodes have arrival sensors, and I have no idea where they are.

Comment: @cammil: but you've given that the walking speed (*distance* per *time*) is constant, so given the walking *time*, you can always derive the desired walking *distance* from that.

Comment: Agreed, the length of the path can be determined. But not the straight line distance (easily) as there are nodes which you cannot walk across.

Comment: @cammil: aha, so you have distances of a set of paths, rather than distances between a set of pairs of nodes?

Comment: Sure it's doable.  You can always guess every possible grid layout with vertices removed and verify that they satisfy the constraints you are given.  So it is in NP.  Do you want a polynomial time (feasible) algorithm?

Comment: @PålGD: interesting way of looking at it. So yes, it is possible, question is, what is a "good" algorithm.

Comment: This seems related to [Multidimensional Scaling (MDS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling), so you might like to use that as a search keyword if you've not heard of it. Standard MDS solves the problem you describe, but without any barriers (i.e. from walk times in an open-plan space, it could create a map showing the relative positions of the destinations).

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go ahead and say yes to this question.

Given that you know the position of the nodes and the walk times between the nodes. Even if the walk times are not consistent I am pretty sure you would be able to use this to best guess the terrain. You could use a Bayesian Network although it is an NP-hard problem.

You would give paths a confidence level based upon a guess of average walk times. You will also need to know the probabilities of it being a faster or slower time and the possible routes for different sets of times. With this information you can then plot the most probable routes for the given time.

You will not know the average walk time accurately so you will feedback your updated plot of the terrain to try and make this figure more accurate.

Using these confidence levels from a combination of all of the nodes available it would seem possible to plot at least the most popular routes around the building and ascertain where obstacles might exist.

The more nodes you have and the more walk information you obtain the more accurate the final map will be but also the more computationally costly it will be as well.

I'm not sure how usable the finished result will be but yes by all means you can best guess it.